# How to create new rows courresponding to current rows in table by changing column value

Tags: mysql, sql

**My Table is**
`emp_activity`

```
id  emp_id     date        time     status
---|------|-------------|----------|---------
1  | 1122 | 20-08-2019  | 09:30 AM | login
2  | 1123 | 20-08-2019  | 09:30 AM | login
5  | 1124 | 20-08-2019  | 09:30 AM | login
3  | 1125 | 20-08-2019  | 09:30 AM | login
4  | 1126 | 20-08-2019  | 09:30 AM | login
6  | 1127 | 20-08-2019  | 09:30 AM | login
7  | 1128 | 20-08-2019  | 09:30 AM | login
8  | 1129 | 20-08-2019  | 09:30 AM | login
```

i want to insert each employees logout rows at 11 PM on this same day in same table like this.

**Wanted Table**
emp_activity

```
id  emp_id     date        time     status
---|------|-------------|----------|---------
1  | 1122 | 20-08-2019  | 09:30 AM | login
2  | 1123 | 20-08-2019  | 09:30 AM | login
5  | 1124 | 20-08-2019  | 09:30 AM | login
3  | 1125 | 20-08-2019  | 09:30 AM | login
4  | 1126 | 20-08-2019  | 09:30 AM | login
6  | 1127 | 20-08-2019  | 09:30 AM | login
7  | 1128 | 20-08-2019  | 09:30 AM | login
8  | 1129 | 20-08-2019  | 09:30 AM | login
9  | 1122 | 20-08-2019  | 11:00 PM | logout
10 | 1123 | 20-08-2019  | 11:00 AM | logout
11 | 1124 | 20-08-2019  | 11:00 AM | logout
12 | 1125 | 20-08-2019  | 11:00 AM | logout
13 | 1126 | 20-08-2019  | 11:00 AM | logout
14 | 1127 | 20-08-2019  | 11:00 AM | logout
15 | 1128 | 20-08-2019  | 11:00 AM | logout
16 | 1129 | 20-08-2019  | 11:00 AM | logout
```

Comment: If you have a follow up question which is very different from what you already asked (and was answered), you should open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `union all` with scalar value insead of a column:

```
select * from MyTable
union all
select id, emp_id, date, cast('11:00:00' as time), 'logout' from MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO emp_activity (emp_id, date, time, status)
SELECT emp_id, date, '11:00 PM', 'logout'
FROM emp_activity
WHERE status = 'login';
```

### Demo

This answer assumes that the `id` column is auto increment, and would be auto populated during the insert by omitting it.  I don't know if you are actually storing things like `09:30 AM` literally in the `time` column.  The time literal for 11PM in MySQL is `23:00:00`, in 24 hour time.

Comment: how could i set this query using cron job

Comment: I don't understand the context of your comment.  Are you wanting to do this from an application, such as Java or C#?  Or directly from MySQL?  In any case, I suggest opening a new question.I

Comment: i want to execute this Query while 11.pm in my server

Answer (score 1):

if your ID column is not auto increment, you can use this script.

```
insert into emp_activity (id, emp_id, date, time, status)
select id + (select count(1) from emp_activity where status = 'login'), emp_id, date, '11:00 PM', 'logout'
from emp_activity
where status = 'login';
```